# My page crashes when i push a value into an array and try to reprint the values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to make a page which automatically loads a list of names and then is able to add text to the list. I have an array which already contains a set of names minus one cell which is left to be undefined. Then I have a function set up so that it looks for any undefined cells and sets that cell to equal what is typed into the text box. Since I am fairly new to coding, I am not exactly sure if there is something vital I am missing and/or I am doing something wrong.

```js
var workers = ["Bob", "Bill"];
workers[3] = "Jill";
var i;
var text = "";

function lister() {
    for (i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
        text += workers[i] + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = text;
}

function putIn(x) {
    for (i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
        if (typeof workers[i] == 'undefined') {
            workers[i] === x;
        } else {
            workers.push(x);
        }
    }

    lister();
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<body onload="lister()">
    <p id="list"></p>
    <input id = "addContent" type = "text" placeholder = "Name">
    <button id="submitIn" value = "Submit" onclick="putIn(addContent.value)">Submit</button>  
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Step one is always to check the developer console. In most browsers it's activated by pressing your F12 key.

Comment: `workers[i] === x;` This is not how you assign a value to a variable. This is how you do it: `workers[i] = x;`.

Comment: Plus, inside the function `lister`, you do not re-initialise the variable `text`, you just append to it and then show the result repeated over and over again. And you do not check if a cell has the value of undefined before appending it to `text`.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why your browser is crashed is because you use `workers.length` in the loop and you increse the length with the `push` so this loop is never ends..

You can just assign a variable to check if its replaced the undefined variable if he exists or if its doesn't to push after the loop.

```
<script>
var workers = ["Bob","Bill"];
workers[3]= "Jill";
var i;
var text= "";
function lister(){
    text = ""; // here you need to reset the text so its won't just add them to the old ones..
    for (i=0 ; i < workers.length ; i++ ) {
        text +=  workers[i] + "<br>";
    } 
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML=text;
}

function putIn(x){
    var isReplaced = 0;
    for(i=0;i<workers.length;i++){
        if (workers[i] == null){
            workers[i] = x;
            isReplaced = 1;
        }
    }

    if(!isReplaced) {
        workers.push(x);
    }

    lister();
}

</script>
```

Comment: use `true`-`false` why use `0`-`1` for `isReplaced`. It's clearer.

Comment: Every time the `putIn` function is called, it is having to loop over the existing items unnecessarily because the `isReplaced` flag is local to the function.

Comment: @Gideon you are right but I don't know where he is going with this. he can also use `filter` function at the begining and remove the undefined items too and then just push new ones..

Comment: @Shibi Fair enough. It's true that the use case is not that clear.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue was in your `putIn` function. The app crashed because it was never going to exit the loop, since you are constantly adding to the array that is being looped over.

We can use a global flag to determine if the gap has been filled or not. If it hasn't, we loop over the array and set the value at the correct index. At this point we can set the flag to `true` and `break` out of the loop. We have completed that update operation. There's nothing else to add.

The subsequent times we call `putIn`, it will add the new items to the list, assuming they don't already exist. I added that bit of logic as I'd imagine that would be a desired restriction.

#### Architecture improvements

I have tidied things up and shown how to add new items to the list, if they don't already exist, and how to handle the case where you want to replace the `undefined` gap.

Nowadays, we bind our events in the JavaScript code rather than in the markup. This is particularly important when it comes to using templates.

The basic idea in my solution is to always use the JavaScript array to drive the UI. We have the `workers` array, and we generate the markup from that. `<ul>` are the most appropriate tag for unordered lists. We can then add `<li>` elements for the items, and append one for each value in the `workers` array.

There's various optimisations you can apply here, but this is the basic idea.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var filledInGap = false;
var workers = ["Bob", "Bill"];
workers[3] = "Jill";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", bindList, false);

submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
    putIn(content.value);
    bindList();
});

function bindList() {
    list.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
        var item = document.createElement("li");
        item.innerHTML = workers[i];
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
}

function putIn(value) {
    if (!filledInGap) {
        for (var i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
            if (typeof(workers[i]) === "undefined") {
                workers[i] = value;
                filledInGap = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else if (workers.indexOf(value) === -1) {
        workers.push(value);
    }
}
```

```css
ul { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>

<input id="content" type="text" placeholder="Name">
<button id="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```